# remove all word in string that contain a word from slice

Tags: string, go, slice

i'm trying to make a topic extraction, what i do is remove all auxiliary word from string, my pseudo-code is :

```
topic := make(map[string]int)
auxiliaryWord := []string{"hbs", "habis", "dan", "kapan", "bagaimana", "kita", "kamu", "warga", "pada", "paling", "ga", "gak", "enggak", "tidak", "bukan", "usai", "juga", "yg", "yang", "kpd", "kepada", "nya", "adanya", "jd", "jadi", "sih", "lah", "kan", "photo", "from", "by", "ini", "saja", "utk", "untuk", "lebih", "ternyata", "apa", "sok", "tau", "bagi", "eksis", "keluar", "kk", "kakak"}
for chat := range chats {
    arrWord := chat.Split(chat, " ")
    for word := arrWord {
        if word not in auxiliaryWord {
            if topic[word] not exist {
                topic[word] = 1
            } else {
                topic[word]+= 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my question is, is there any faster way to do this ?

Comment: You can use a `map`, instead of `slice`, to save the `auxiliaryWord`

Comment: Why is `topic` a `map[string]int`? Large `map[string]interface{}` maps become less performant, because `string`s escape to the heap (because they contain pointers). You should benchmark it, but using a `[]string` might be faster for lookup.

Comment: @minitauros i need to count (int) how much a topic (string) mentioned from chat

Comment: Yeah I guess it will only be minor in most cases, just something to think about if you want to micro tweak things :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just precalculate auxilaryWord to hash, then do a lookup.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

var auxilaryWords = []string{"hbs", "habis", "dan", "kapan", "bagaimana", "kita", "kamu", "warga", "pada", "paling", "ga", "gak", "enggak", "tidak", "bukan", "usai", "juga", "yg", "yang", "kpd", "kepada", "nya", "adanya", "jd", "jadi", "sih", "lah", "kan", "photo", "from", "by", "ini", "saja", "utk", "untuk", "lebih", "ternyata", "apa", "sok", "tau", "bagi", "eksis", "keluar", "kk", "kakak"}
var auxHash = map[string]bool{}

func CountTopics(chatWords []string) map[string]int {
    result := map[string]int{}
    for _, word := range chatWords {
        if !auxHash[word] {
            result[word] += 1
        }
    }
    return result
}

func init() {
    for _, word := range auxilaryWords {
        auxHash[word] = true
    }
}

func main() {
    arrWord := strings.Split(`hai kakak habis makan apa`, " ")
    fmt.Println(CountTopics(arrWord))   
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Wr2gK_zizL0

Comment: you could just use a single map of [string]int, test for existence and increment that